# What is wrong with this very simple C program that uses strings?

Tags: c, c-strings

I haven't used C since the 90's so I'm probably having a brain fart, but what is wrong with the program below?  With gcc 4.8 I get various warnings and then a segmentation fault when running.  Thanks for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_string(char **a, char **b)
{
    printf("a string: \"%s\"\n", a[5]);
    printf("another string: \"%s\"\n", b[9]);

    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    char a[10][10];
    char b[10][10];

    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
        {
            a[i][j] = 'x';
            b[i][j] = 'y';
        }
        a[i][9] = '\0';
        b[i][9] = '\0';
    }

    printf("a string: \"%s\"\n", a[3]);
    printf("another string: \"%s\"\n", b[7]);
    print_string(a, b); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The warnings are probably useful ...

Comment: Fix the warnings first, then ask a question. Or ask how to fix the warnings if that is what you are stuck on.  Posting the warnings is probably as useful as posting the code - we won't have to compile it to find out what they are for starters, and my compiler may produce different warnings than yours.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't know the dimensions of your multi-dimensional arrays `a` and `b`, so you have to specify them in the function declaration:

```
void print_string(char a[][10], char b[][10])
```

**And in details:**

- In function `main`, you declare an array `char a[10][10]`, which contains 100 `char`s
- The compiler **correctly** translates `a[i]` as `(char*)((int)a+10*sizeof(char)*i)`
- Then, you pass it to function `print_string`, where it's declared as pointer `char** a`
- The compiler **incorrectly** translates `a[i]` as `(char*)((int)a+sizeof(char*)*i)`

Comment: Well, I'll delete my gripe then. Thanks for editing.

Comment: @mike.dld: As far as I can tell, they **are** pointers to character data.

Comment: @mike.dld; You should work on your pointer and arrays concept.

Comment: I'm reading http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html, and although I can see how to get my code to work, I still don't understand what's going on or why knowing the size of the memory used by the array is what is causing problems.  If the value of "a" in my code is just an address and if each a[0], a[1], etc. are also addresses, why can't "a" be assigned to and used interchangeably with a variable of type char **?  If I use it to access memory that isn't allocated, that's my problem, but that clearly doesn't happen in the code shown.

Comment: @user3268289: I added a detailed description of the problem, though I hope to get a few comments here to assert that.

Answer (score 2):

You assumed that arrays are pointers. A pointer to pointer to not a 2D array. `a` and `b` are of type `char (*)[10]` after decay to pointers, but your function expects arguments of type `char **`. Always remember that **arrays are not pointers**.
Change your function to

```
void print_string(char (*a)[10], char (*b)[10]) {...}
```

Comment: Actually, arrays *are* pointers. Array *elements* OTOH in this case aren't.

Comment: Also, the assignments are inside the `i` loop where the index value should be valid. The variable that whose value is 10 is `j`.

Comment: @mike.dld:  No they are *different*. Given `char a[10]` and `char* b = a` for example, compare `sizeof(a)` to `sizeof(b)` and you get different answers - the size of the array a and the sizeof the pointer b.  What is true is that arrays are not *first class data types* and when passed as parameters, "decay" to a pointer to the array - and the size information is lost .

Comment: @Clifford I don't see any code relying on `sizeof()` here, what's your point?

Comment: @MOehm; Yes. I missed that. Edited my answer.

Comment: @mike.dld; Actually, ***arrays are not pointers***. Prove it if I am wrong.

Comment: @mike.dld arrays and pointer are different and accessed in different ways, check out the classic       extern char*a and the extern char a[] problem.

Comment: @mike.dld:  My point is that arrays *are not* pointers.  The point about `sizeof`is merely a demonstration of *how* they differ.  The point is about the language semantics not about this specific question.  The worrying thing is that someone saw fit to up-vote your comment.

Comment: `a` and `b` objects in `main` are of type `char [10][10]` not `char (*)[10]`.

Comment: @ouah:  True, but not in the context of `print_string()` where the first dimension is unknown and does not need to be known.  Specifically the GCC warning is `expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[10]'`.  The argument "decays" to a pointer - albeit a pointer to a `char[10]` array.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to know that `a[i]` is actually `*(a+i)`. As we know, the result of `a+i` is `a_as_number + i * sizeof(*a)`. You can tell that for `char** a`, `sizeof(*a)` is 8 (on a 64 bit platform), while for `char a[10][10]`, `sizeof(*a)` is 10 (ten chars).

Pointers contain both run-time address *and* compile-time type info. Those two pointers have different type info. To correct that, just change your array in main into an array of pointers and let them point to somewhere.

Comment: While the solution ultimately requires a type match between the variables in `main()` and the parameters of `print_string()`, it is simpler to correct the types of the parameters in this case that to change the type of the variable.  The problem is the *"and let them point to somewhere* - that unnecessarily requires additional code and additional data (the *"somewhere"*) to be instantiated.

Comment: @Clifford `print_string(char**)` style is more general and practical, like `main(int, char**)`. But in this specific question, yes, just change the parameter to `char[][10]`.

Comment: agreed, in this situation is is an odd and probably unsafe interface, but it looks like an academic exercise only.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your should read and fix your code that generates warnings. Iff you still don't understand why your code is not working, below is your example with debug printfs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_string(char **a, char **b)
{
    printf("in print_string\n");
    printf("a = %p\n", a); // outputs pointer's value
    printf("a[5] = %p\n", a[5]); //outputs the value stored at (a + 5*sizeof(pointer)), which you pass to printf
    printf("a[5] = %p\n", *(a + 5)); //same as above
    printf("a[5] address = %p\n", &a[5]);
    printf("a[5] address = %p\n", (a + 5));
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    char a[10][10];
    char b[10][10];

    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
        {
            a[i][j] = 'x';
            b[i][j] = 'y';
        }
        a[i][9] = '\0';
        b[i][9] = '\0';
    }

    printf("a string: \"%s\"\n", a[3]);
    printf("another string: \"%s\"\n", b[7]);

    printf("a's address = %p\n", a);
    printf("a[0, 0]'s address = %p\n", &a[0][0]);
    printf("a[1, 0]'s address = %p\n", &a[1][0]);
    printf("a[5, 0]'s address = %p\n", &a[5][0]);
    print_string(a, b); 


    return 0;
}
```